# Print a value in Python from oracle database

Tags: python, oracle

I have an issue when displaying  a value in python retrieved from oracle table into CLOB field:

Oracle query:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(t.xml), '/DCResponse/ResponseInfo/ApplicationId') 
  FROM table t 
 WHERE id = 2
```

Value displayed in Oracle Client

```
5701200
```

Python code

```
import cx_Oracle 
conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("user/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(t.xml),'/DCResponse/ResponseInfo/ApplicationId') FROM table t where id = 2""")
for row in cursor:
print(row)
```

Python Console: Nothing is displayed!!! I want to show:5701200

Please Help.
Best Regards
Giancarlo

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few issues with your code :

- Replace `cx_Oracle.Connection` with `cx_Oracle.connect`
- Be careful about the indentation related to the `print(row)`
- Triple double-quotes, within the SELECT statement, are redundant,
  replace them with Single double-quotes
- Prefer Using `print(row[0])` in order to return the desired number rather than
  a tuple printed.

  ```
  import cx_Oracle 
  conn = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pwd@localhost:1521/orcl')
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  query  = "SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(t.xml),'/DCResponse/ResponseInfo/ApplicationId')"
  query += "  FROM tab t "
  query += " WHERE t.ID = 2 "

  cursor.execute( query )
  for row in cursor:
      print(row[0])
  ```

Assigning a query to a variable not required, as stated in my case, but preferable to use in order to display the long SELECT statement decently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over result, use this one:

```
for row in cursor.execute("sql_query")
    print(row)
```

or you can fetch each row like this:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("sql_query")
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
```